# What's the difference between LD3( multipule structure) and LD3 (single structure) in ARMv8-A structure

Tags: arm, load, neon

I knew from an official document on ARMv8-A that LD3 instruction has two forms. One is for single structure and the other is for multiple structure. I know the difference about their utilities, but I wonder, since they are both called "LD3", how can I define whether it's for multiple or single structure? Namely, what's the difference when writing these two kinds of instructions.

[image]
[image]

I noticed that for LD3(single structure) instruction, there's a part called `<index>`, but I can't figure out what `index` here really means and what should I write to replace it.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The differences are illustrated below:

```
ld3     {v0.16b, v1.16b, v2.16b}, [x0]

ld3     {v0.b, v1.b, v2.b}[2], [x0]
```

The first one will load 48 bytes while the latter one loads only three bytes.

Let's assume that `x0` is pointing on an 8bit array from 0 to 47

```
v0: 45  42  39  36  33  30  27  24  21  18  15  12  9   6   3   0
v1: 46  43  40  37  34  31  28  25  22  19  16  13  10  7   4   1
v2: 47  44  41  38  35  32  29  26  23  20  17  14  11  8   5   2
```

vs

```
v0: x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   0   x   x
v1: x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   1   x   x
v2: x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   2   x   x
```

where `x` means the old values in the registers remaining unchanged.

Comment: So the index [2] here means the position of the bits to be filled in, right?

If I change the [2] to [3], namely change the instruction into:
ld3     {v0.b,  v1.b,  v2.b} [3], [x0]
Then the bits in these three registers should be:
v0: x    x    x    x    x    x    x    x    x    x    x    x    0    x    x    x
v1: x    x    x    x    x    x    x    x    x    x    x    x    1    x    x    x
v2: x    x    x    x    x    x    x    x    x    x    x    x    2    x    x    x

Is the change in position of bits like this right?

Comment: @Lazyloper yes.